# Function within component throwing an error message

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I have a component with two functions defined in the methods section. Each make an API call for some JSON data.

The second function is dependent on the first one having already run (I need data from the first to inform the second). My `HTML` calls function one and renders it. Within that newly rendered content is a `v-on:click` call that calls the second function, and passes it a value that was created from the first function.

The code is as follows:

**HTML**

```
<div v-for="team in hockeyDataList.teams" :key="team.id">

              <!-- Loop through the teams array -->      
              <img :src="`https://www-league.nhlstatic.com/images/logos/teams-current-primary-dark/${team.id}.svg`" class="img-round team-logo"/>
              <h1>{{ team.name }}</h1>
              <div>Division: {{ team.division.name }} <br/> Conference: {{ team.conference.name }}</div>

              <h2>Roster</h2>
              <div class="player-cont">
                  <div v-on:click="getPlayerData(player)" v-for="player in team.roster.roster" :key="team.id + '-' + player.person.id" class="col" :id="player.person.id">
                      <h3>{{ player.person.fullName }}</h3>
                      <img :src="`https://cms.nhl.bamgrid.com/images/headshots/current/168x168/${player.person.id}.jpg`" class="img-round"/>
                      <div>
                      Number: {{ player.jerseyNumber }} | Position: {{ player.position.abbreviation }} 
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
         
   </div>
```

**VUE**

```
data() {
      return {
        hockeyDataList: [],
        playerDataList: []
    },
    methods: {

    getHockeyData(teams) {      
        axios.get("https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/teams/" + teams.id + "?expand=team.roster").then(response => (this.hockeyDataList = response.data));
      }
    },    
    getPlayerData(player) {
       axios.get("https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/" + player.person.id + "/stats?stats=yearByYear").then(response => (this.playerDataList = response.data));
    }
  };
```

The error is being produced when I fire the second call is:

```
Property or method "getPlayerData" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render
```

I'm new to Vue and am unsure what this error is trying to get me to correct.

Comment: The problem is bad formatting that doesn't allow the code to be easily read by anybody.

Comment: It pasted in that way. Surely a more productive comment could be supplied, the odd indentation out of place seldom produces an error message.

Comment: All of us paste the code at SO, it takes some efforts. It's not indentation itself but that it made it hard to spot a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote your **getPlayerData** method outside of ***methods*** block, move it back in.

```
    methods: {

getHockeyData(teams) {      
    axios.get("https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/teams/" + teams.id + "?expand=team.roster").then(response => (this.hockeyDataList = response.data));
  },
getPlayerData(player) {
   axios.get("https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/" + player.person.id + "/stats?stats=yearByYear").then(response => (this.playerDataList = response.data));
  }
},
```

Also ***data*** and ***methods*** are 2 separate blocks like

```
data() {
return{};
},
methods:{
},
computed:{
}
```